# how to load multiple files into multiple destination table in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

HI I Have one doubt in ssis,
 source Location have different files each file name is comes with location name .here we want load
each file name corresponding  tables  using ssis package.

source loacation  have multiples files for each locationname files;
exaple:Files location : c:\Sourcefile\
Filesnames comes like : hyd files,bang files.
Hyd files comes like: hyd.txt,hyd1.txt hyd2.txt all are same structure only.hyd related all files load into hyd table only.
bang files comes like: bang.txt,bang.txt bang2.txt all are same structure only.bang related all files load into bang table only.
all source files and target tables structure are same only.

source FIles Structure: for hyd.txt file

```
Id,name,loc
1,abc,hyd
2,hari,hyd
for hyd1.txt file
id,name,loc
4,banu,hyd
5,ran,hyd

similar to bang:
id,name,loc
10,gop,bang
11,union,loc
for bang1.txt file
id,name,loc
14,ja,bang
```

here all hyd related text files load into hyd table in sql server database table. similar to bang fils load into bang table.
hyd table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hyd](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [loc] [varchar](50) NULL
)
 similar to bang
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bang](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [loc] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

I tried like below:
[image]
[image]
above one tables names not getting dynamically.  i kept statistically values in table variable. that time all location related records are loaded into one table.
how to load multiple files into multiple destination table in ssis.please tell me how to achive this task in ssis

Comment: why cant u add 2 data flow tasks ?

Comment: I agree with @BHouse , 2 data flows seems a more efficient way of doing the job but in your current package I would say that the problem is the update of the location variable, you probably need a script task to do the update.

Comment: actually in my source  side have 100 + filenames are there.so we cannot do 100 dft.again in the feature it may add.so we need to do  dynamically in the destination tables passing based on filename.

Comment: You could do one for hyd and one for bang and load in parallel but in any case i think the problem is the update of the variable location, are you doing it within the derived column transformation?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots i have 3 suggestions:

1. You have to set the Data Flow Task `Delay Validation` property to `True`
2. You have to change the `User::location` variable value outside the Data flow task, you can add an expression task before the data flow task with the following expression

   ```
   @[User::location] = SUBSTRING(@[User::FileName],1,FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName,".",1) -1)
   ```

   *or use a script component to achieve this*
3. Or you can add a script task followed 2 data flow tasks inside the for each loop, the script task check the filename: if it is `hyd` it execute the first DFT , if  it is `bang` it execute the second: *(check this link: [Working with Precedence Constraints in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/))*